# Unable to store any value in array

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am unable to put the value in the first element of the array. It's always asking to put the value in array second element.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, i;
    char names[50][50];
    
    printf("\nEnter the number of names you want :");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d name :", i);
        gets(names[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\nThe required name lists :");
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d name :", i+1);
        puts(names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never *ever* use the `gets` function. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it even have been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` will write) is by default *line buffered*, which means the output will be written to the terminal on newline. Therefore you should make it a habit to only use *trailing* newlines when printing. The leading newline in your code will cause the *previous* line to be written.

Answer (score 2):

As `scanf` leaves behind a dangling newline character `\n` it causes the `gets`(Use `fgets`) to not wait for the input from the user. Try flushing the input buffer by using `getchar`.

**Update:** Added mechanism to remove the trailing `\n` registered by the `fgets`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int a,i;
    printf("Enter the number of names you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    //Flush the input buffer
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    char names[50][50];
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%d name: ",i);
        fgets(names[i],50,stdin); //Use fgets instead of gets
        // To remove th \n registed by the fgets
        char *p;
        if ((p = strchr(names[i], '\n')) != NULL)
           *p = '\0';
    }
    printf("The required name lists: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
       printf("%d name: ",i+1);
       puts(names[i]);
  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reference:

1. [Remove newline skipped by scanf](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284392&answer=1044873249)
2. [Remove newline registered by fgets](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044652485&id=1043284385)

Comment: Instead of having that long mechanism, you can use `scanf(" %50s", names[i]);` It'll automatically flush out any trailing whitespace character. In other words, it'll not register the previous `\n` character from input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Put this after line scanf("%d",&a), as a workaround,

```
    char c;
    scanf("%c",&c);
```

Also use **fgets(names[i],50,stdin)** instead of **gets(names[i])**

Note: You get warning when you use gets in your code, as it is always assumes a consistent input from user. More explanation over here
[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: What if the user inputs: `2    \n` or something like that. Then it won't work.